# Apply separate dataframe of 0 - 1 int values as color gradient map to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colormap

I'm generating a table for my fantasy football league which pulls everyone's scores each week and compares them against all other teams to generate a weekly "league record" stored in a dataframe called `exDf`. It looks like this:

[image]

Separately, I'm also generated a dataframe of normalized 0-1 values based on the number of wins and stores that in another dataframe `color_df`. So for each week, the lowest scoring team (0-11) will generate 0 and the highest scoring team (11-0) will generate a 1. It looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is use the background_gradient portion of the dataframe_image library to colormap the weekly scores from 0 being red to 1 being green with a gradient in between. I'm using a regex filter to try and make the color_map dataframe and the exDf dataframe the same shape to apply the gradient to.

```
dfi.export(exDf.style.hide(axis='index').background_gradient(axis=0, subset=exDf.filter(regex='Week'), gmap=color_df.filter(regex='Week')),f'{year}_Week_{weekNum}.png')
```

I've been trying to go through the options on the pandas styler page (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.background_gradient.html) but don't understand the gmap/cmap functions.

Answer (score 0):

The code below colors the cells of the data frame according to the records in the correct way. I think a regex filter is unnecessary if you have matching column names in both data frames, see the `subset` option of `background_gradient`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Week 1": "11-0", "Week 2": "10-1"},
        {"Week 1": "0-11", "Week 2": "1-10"},
        {"Week 1": "5-6", "Week 2": "4-7"},
    ]
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Week 1": 1, "Week 2": 0.9, "junk": 999},
        {"Week 1": 0.1, "Week 2": 0.1, "junk": 999},
        {"Week 1": 0.5, "Week 2": 0.4, "junk": 999},
    ]
)
df.style.background_gradient(
    axis=None, gmap=df2, cmap="Reds", subset=["Week 1", "Week 2"]
)
```